# how to i use mx:html to catch the 302 redirect when use the locationchange event

Tags: html, apache-flex, oauth, air, http-status-code-302

I want to to a air application to make an OAuth application.
but when i get 302 redirect, the `locationChange` event of the `mx:html`can't be fired

Answer (score 0):

You can set html.location, and you can catch the redirect by watching the html.location on the locationChange event.

If you want to catch the redirect before the html component uses it, you could try and hook the htmlLoader